# Optimum return probability Risk calculation

Tags: python-3.x, probability, probability-theory, risk-analysis, tensorflow-probability

I have a trading system that I developed for Forex markets.
When I analyze the results, I need to do an optimum level analysis to create my entry level.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPoeX.png]
As seen in the picture;

In the first trade result, the peak level (range value) was 50, and in return, 20 units were added to the range value. This means that 20 units of profit will be written if direct processing is entered when the range value is passed.

In the second and third transactions, even if the impassable trade position is opened, at least 20 units are being profit.

Logically, at least 20 units were targeted and 4. When processing is entered;
20 units of profit cannot be achieved and 29 units with range value will be damaged.

If the intended profit figure is not reached, the range value will be damaged.
How can I get a solution based on this data?

Thank you for your answers already.

Comment: Could you please clarify the problem in terms that non-forex traders can understand, and, if possible, include any code or solutions that you have tried yourself?

Comment: I have a system that produces results in the picture I share. I don't have any software to interpret the results in the image